# How to make a responsive navigation menu remain at the top of a page?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm now working on a responsive navigation menu so that my page will be compatible with different platforms. I followed the steps here: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp/ but I couldn't make it remain the same position when I shrank the window (I made the menu always remain at the top when my page is on a wide screen). how to make it remain at the top as every navigation bar is meant to?

Comment: position:fixed (if you want it to stay there even when scrolling) or position: absolute (if you just want it at the top of the page, but not at the top of your browser window); top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;

Comment: Thank you. But when I changed position to fixed and clicked the icon, the whole bar would kind of deform and not look like a bar..

Comment: it looks like this. https://i.imgsafe.org/c810d924b2.png

Comment: can you post your html and css please? Or create a jsfiddle to show the code?

Comment: Thank you. I just got it fixed. It turned out I got something wrong. Your method works well.

Comment: @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: fixed;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

Comment: ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
}

Comment: That is how I fixed it.

Comment: OK great! It's always best if you can figure it out yourself with the advice of others =) I added it as an my comment as an answer anyways. If you found it helpful maybe you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to add positioning to your navigation bar:

```
position: fixed; /* if you want it to stay there even when scrolling */
position: absolute; /* if you just want it at the top of the page, but not at the top of your browser window */
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```